# How to get around NSIS download error "connecting to host"

Tags: download, nsis

So I'm trying to download and install PySVN as part of my program's stack. I'm downloading it rather than including, but the download is failing for unknown reasons. Here's the code:

```
!define PYSVN_FILE "py25-pysvn-svn161-1.7.0-1177.exe"   
!define PYSVN_DOWNLOAD_LOC "http://pysvn.tigris.org/files/documents/1233/45661/py25-pysvn-svn161-1.7.0-1177.exe"
${If} $pythonVersion == "2.5"
     NSISdl::download "${PYSVN_DOWNLOAD_LOC}" ${PYSVN_FILE}
${Else}
     NSISdl::download "${PYSVN2_DOWNLOAD_LOC}" ${PYSVN_FILE}
${EndIf}
```

Where ${PYSVN_DOWNLOAD_LOC} = http://pysvn.tigris.org/files/documents/1233/45661/py25-pysvn-svn161-1.7.0-1177.exe is what I'm trying to download.

The file obviously downloads fine from a web browser, but NSIS throws a "connecting to host" error when it tries to connect. I've tried giving it a big timeout value. Is this a proxy issue? How can I get around this without including the file in my installer?

**Edit:**

Thanks to Anders I've edited my code as follows:

```
  ${If} $pythonVersion == "2.5"
        inetc::get "${PYSVN_DOWNLOAD_LOC}" "${PYSVN_FILE}" /END
  ${Else}
        inetc::get "${PYSVN2_DOWNLOAD_LOC}" "${PYSVN_FILE}" /END
  ${EndIf}
```

Which now gives me a "302 (redirection)" error. The file and download location have not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inetc::get /NOCANCEL /RESUME "" "http://file.blah" "$TEMP\Setup.exe"
    Pop $0
    StrCmp $0 "OK" dlok
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Error downloading. Click OK to abort installation." /SD IDOK
dlok:
    !insertmacro closeAllBrowsers
    ; install plugin
    ExecWait `$TEMP\Setup.exe`
```

Answer (score 2):

NSISdl uses plain sockets and will fail if the server does redirect and cookie tricks/tracking, try [INetC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in), it uses the higher level WinInet API

Comment: This is giving me a 302 "redirection" error. I've been looking for anything that deals with this error specifically but it seems there's nothing?

Comment: INetC worked for me. Fire up Wireshark and take a look at what is going on when it fails...

Comment: I tried Wireshark (I'm not familiar with it) and it gives a TCP retransmission: 302 moved temporarily message when I attempt to download. I think there is an HTML redirect page there which is pointing to http://pysvn.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentDownload?documentID=45661, which also gives the same error. I am using the code "inetc::get "${PYSVN_DOWNLOAD_LOC}" ${PYSVN_FILE}" I don't think I'm missing any options here...

Comment: InetC command should end with /END. See http://nsis.pastebin.com/c8iH7Dmk for my code

Comment: I changed my code to match yours, but it is still giving the same error... maybe since it's relying on WinInet, the operating system plays a role? I'm doing this on an XP SP3 vm...

Comment: IE 8 was set on its default settings (medium security, allows most third and first party cookies). I've changed that to allow all cookies to no avail.